send certificate in python request
I'm new to using Python and I'm facing a problem using the requests library.
I want to send my digital certificate in a request, so I combined my private_key and public_key in a single line and created a temporary file to be sent in the request, like this:


import requests
import os
import tempfile
import sys
import certifi
import certifi.core
import requests.utils
import requests.adapters
session = requests.Session()

private = '''
<private text>
'''
publica = '''
<public text>
'''



cert = (private, publica)

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_key_file:
    temp_key_file.write('\n'.join(cert).encode('utf-8'))
    temp_key_path = temp_key_file.name


url = "<my url>"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
payload = "my payload"

session.cert = cert
   response = session.request('post',url, headers=headers, data=payload,cert=temp_key_path, verify=False)

print(response.text)



This way I get exactly the result I want, and it works very well. but, I cannot use a temporary file on my server, for reasons beyond my control.
so I did:


import requests
import os
import tempfile
import sys
import certifi
import certifi.core
import requests.utils
import requests.adapters
session = requests.Session()

private = '''
<private text>
'''
publica = '''
<public text>
'''



cert = (private, publica)

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_key_file:
    temp_key_file.write('\n'.join(cert).encode('utf-8'))
    temp_key_path = temp_key_file.name


url = "<url text>"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
payload = "<my payload>"

response = session.request('post',url, headers=headers, data=payload, cert=cert, verify=False)

print(response.text)



and trying without sending the temporary file I get an error, an error saying:
OSError: Could not find the TLS certificate file, invalid path:
Why does this happen? requests apparently only accepts the request if I send a path, but I can't send a path even if it's temporary... can anyone help me?
